# Apache Tomcat configuration

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration

I have 2 webapps running in Tomcat. Is it possible to configure Tomcat so that first webapp is mapped to **www.example.com** and **www.example.com/webapp1** simultaneously, and second webapp is mapped to **www.example.com/webapp2**?

Answer (score 0):

yes just wrap up the projects in war files as :

- ROOT.war
- webapp1.war
- webapp2.war

And then copy to your deploy/webapp directory.

Comment: NimChimpsky, thanks, but I want only one copy of webapp1 currently running in container. Is it possible?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry just re-read your question. Should be fairly simple, just map the request string "webapp1", to the entry point of your first project, in its servlet.xml file, if i remember correctly.